# Banco de dados com problemas pra acentuação

Tags: php, mysql

O banco Mysql não tinha suporte a acentuação, mudei a codificação para o padrão utf8_general_ci e agora passou a exibir os dados corretamente no cliente, mas mesmo assim as  palavras ficam bugadas tipo Você fica VocÃª, e se eu tentar fazer um acentuação diretamente no banco ocorrem erros. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não sou nenhum expert, porém faço o que posso!! No meu BD as palavras também ficam "bugadas", porém isso nao tem problema, pois na hora do echo você só precisa colocar um <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />... Ao menos comigo resolve!

Answer (score 2):

seguinte, p/ fazer a configuração de charset do mysql+php até a visualização do HTML tem que configurar o  arquivo my.ini ou my.cnf dependendo da plataforma

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

o arquivo php.ini

```
[php]
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

no HTML pode usar a tag

```
<http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

ou setar no arquivo httpd.conf de configuração do apache o parametro

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```